# Magento 2 Fedex Integration Issue with restricted proxy - "Shipping method unavailable"

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, fedex, proxy

I tried integrating the shipping method in my personal laptop and it is working there without any network configuration. But when I'm using different proxy on another PC, I can't get the shipping method working. I tried almost everything to **bypass the localhost requests across the restricted proxy** but nothing seem to work and I'm still searching ways to make it work somehow..
**Here's the picture of debug.log :** 
 [image] 
**Message on frontend :** 
 [image]